# Allow users to embed my content into their sites — Php

Tags: php, css, html

I'm building a Php app, and what I want to do is offer my users the option to embed my content onto their own sites via embeddable code.

In other words, I want to have a page with some content on it, and a button that says **"Embed"**. When users click that, a small bit of embeddable code will appear, which they can copy and paste onto their blog, etc.   This will display the content from my page.

What is the best way of going about this? Please be as descriptive as possible, as I'm kind of new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Please add a code snippet so we can see what you have tried already.  Please include a little bit more information as to how you are determining what the code snippet is going to do.  Ex.  Is there a form where they are slecting properties, are you using values from the user's information, or are you using information taken from a page that is being displayed.  What does the code need to do? Thanks

Comment: As it stands, this is too broad a question. Which part of this question do you need help with? Be specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check other embeded codes from sites like twitter or youtube, each shows a different way to do it depending on the content you're trying to embed.

You can make a javascript file designed to give format (style) and get data asynchronouslly if you need to, and generate some html with the text you want to insert.

So the given code could be something like:

```
<blockquote class="my-class">My ccontent</blockquote>
<script async src="https://mywebsite.com/embed-javascript/javascript-file.js></script>
```

If you use something like this make sure to only affect your code's style and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an embed button that then shows code to copy by changing the display and this is much easier with jQuery.

```js
function showEmbed() {
  $("#code").css("display", "block");
}
```

```css
textarea {
  display: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="showEmbed()">Embed</button><br>
<textarea id="code"><iframe src="//www.google.com.au/"></iframe></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other users suggested already is to use a javascript snippet that they will embed. That script will dynamically created HTML content based on some parameters.

Another approach is to use an **iframe**. This is the **OLD SCHOOL** method if i can call it like that.

But the methods depend on the content type.

If you are going to use just a simple html use the second one, because javascript is something that is executed on the client side and therefore is more **brittle**.

I will suggest you to give us some code example, so we can give you back more accurate answers.
Good luck!